# Log messages except from a particular package to a file

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I am using log4j for logging , my requirement is to log all the logs from package

pkg1 (except pkg1.pkg2) to pkg1.log

and pkg1.pkg2 (a sub package of the above package) to pkg2.log

is this possible ? I know i can achieve it through custom appenders but is there a way I can do it through configurations.

I am using the below properties file. Here the problem is PKG1.log contains logs from PKG2 also.

```
    # Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=WARN, CONSOLE
# Direct log messages to a log file

log4j.logger.com.pkg1=DEBUG, PKG1 log4j.appender.PKG1=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.PKG1.File=logs/PKG1.log
log4j.appender.PKG1.MaxFileSize=1MB
log4j.appender.PKG1.MaxBackupIndex=1
log4j.appender.PKG1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.PKG1.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n


log4j.logger.com.pkg1.pkg2=DEBUG, PKG2
log4j.appender.PKG2=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.PKG2.File=logs/PKG2.log
log4j.appender.PKG2.MaxFileSize=1MB
log4j.appender.PKG2.MaxBackupIndex=1
log4j.appender.PKG2.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.PKG2.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n


# Direct log messages to CONSOLE
log4j.appender.CONSOLE=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

Comment: this question might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5270052/how-to-exclude-a-single-class-from-a-log4j-logger-appender

Comment: I tried this, but the problem is it doesnt log PKG2 at all. I need PKG2 to be logged by another appender.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can stop `PKG2`'s logs from reaching it's ancestor's appenders by disabling the `additivity` flag in the configuration:

```
 log4j.appender.PKG2.additivity=false
```

Comment: It almost worked. But I had to add log4j.additivity.com.pkg1.pkg2=false not log4j.appender.PKG2.additivity=false . Thanks a lot