# Is there a way to disable java.util.logging and enable it back later?

Tags: java, logging, java.util.logging

I'm using a library that logs a bunch of stuff that I don't want to log. It's using `java.util.logging`.

I also don't want to completely disable its logging since some of its logs are useful. Since the unwanted lines are logged only when I run a certain task, if there was a global way of disabling and enabling logging it would solve my problem.

Ideally something like:

```
disableLogging();
taskThatMakesUnnecessaryLogs();
enableLogging();
```

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5270052/how-to-exclude-a-single-class-from-a-log4j-logger-appender

Comment: Also possibly related: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/manual/filters.html

Comment: Basically, there are better ways to do what you want to do than what you're proposing.

Comment: @Michael name any

Comment: You didnt name any.

Comment: @Michael both links you posted have to do with log4j, not util.logging

Comment: Yes you did linked, Iv asked you to name it ;)

Comment: @puhlen That's why I didn't flag as a duplicate. That's the good way to do it. Sure, you can go for a square-peg-round-hole with `util.logging`, but why would you?

Comment: @Michael The library is using util.logging. I could fork the library and change the source code so that it doesn't make the unnecessary logs but that seems worse. So using a different logging framework is out of the question. I know it's not ideal but i need a way of making this work with util.logging

Comment: @Sarp Ah yes, I forgot it was a library. In which case, you can use [an SLF4J bridge](https://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html).

Comment: @Michael util.logging is fine.  There are many good logging libraries out there, log4j isn't the only option.

Comment: @puhlen I didn't say `j.u.l` wasn't fine or that `log4j` is the only option. I said `j.u.l` is not suited for this use-case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For a global impact you can use [`LogManager.reset()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/logging/LogManager.html#reset()) as your call to disable logging and to re-enable logging you can [`LogManager.readConfiguration()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/logging/LogManager.html#readConfiguration()).  However, [there are some major flaws in what actually gets reloaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16441467/use-of-readconfiguration-method-in-logging-activities).  The newer JDK9 method [LogManager.updateConfiguration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16441467/use-of-readconfiguration-method-in-logging-activities/36069135#36069135) should be used instead.

If you know the logger name you can edit your logging.properties to modify the level of that offending logger or create a [filter](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-logging/filters.html).

From code you can locate the logger and change it's level to `OFF` or something higher than the log messages you are seeing.

```
final Logger chatty = Logger.getLogger("somelogger");
final Level oldLevel = chatty.getLevel();
chatty.setLevel(Level.OFF);
try {
  taskThatMakesUnnecessaryLogs();
} finally {
  chatty.setLevel(oldLevel);
}
```