# How to exclude a single class from logging in log4j2

Tags: java, xml, log4j, log4j2

I am using log4j2 for logging in my project, with log4j2.xml as a configuration file. I have a class that constantly floods my log file. Is there a way to exclude this class from logging?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to exclude a single Class from a Log4j Logger / Appender?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5270052/how-to-exclude-a-single-class-from-a-log4j-logger-appender)

Comment: @sai yea, I figured how to adapt it to log4j2, thanks

Answer (score 4):

[How to exclude a single Class from a Log4j Logger / Appender?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5270052/how-to-exclude-a-single-class-from-a-log4j-logger-appender)
In this post I found the answer for the log4j.
And adapted it like this to work with log4j2:

```
<Loggers>
    <Logger name="path.to.your.Class" level="off"/>
</Loggers>
```