# How to remove unnecessary logs from log4j2 log's file

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng, log4j2

I want to remove the unnecessary log's that are generated automatically by **log4j** when i run my suite, I only want the log's which i wrote in the code, please help.

[image]

As you can see my actual log's starts from **Launched flipcart.com** and end with **Closed the current window**
Also check the log4j2.xml file.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See second answer in [How to exclude a single Class from a Log4j Logger / Appender?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5270052/how-to-exclude-a-single-class-from-a-log4j-logger-appender)

Replace

```
<logger name="com.example.FifthClass">
    <level value="FATAL"/>
</logger>
```

with e.g.

```
<logger name="io.netty">
    <level value="FATAL"/>
</logger>
```